# "The Liberator" and Bolívar's death

Tags: historical-accuracy, the-liberator

In the film "[The Liberator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2387513/)" (Spanish: Libertador), a 2013 Spanish-Venezuelan movie starring Edgar Ramírez, the death of Simón Bolívar is depicted as he being murdered, as opposed to accepted history that records him as dying from tuberculosis.

Why would the film depict Bolívar's death in this controversial manner?  Are there any documented references that point to actual foul play?